# How do I create a csv file with dynamically rows

Tags: java, csv, groovy, export

I just can't figure out how to create a csv file with dynamically rows. 
I used commons-csv to write 3 rows to a file but I need some more.

I'm reading values out of a database line by line which look like that:

```
[ID:1,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 856830, VAL1:'36,704'],
[ID:4,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:12:00', VALUE: 736830, VAL1:'1,14'],
[ID:5,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 656830, VAL1:'12,504'],
[ID:5,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:50:00', VALUE: 936830, VAL1:'5,18'],
[ID:3,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 736860, VAL1:'3,4'],
[ID:4,TSP:'2018-01-01 00:50:00', VALUE: 726830, VAL1:'9,14']
```

I wanna create a .csv file with a formatting like that:

```
TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00) | VALUE_ID1 | VAL_ID1 | VALUE_ID3 | VAL_ID3 | VALUE_ID5 | VAL_ID5

TSP(2018-01-01 00:12:00) | VALUE_ID4 | VAL_ID4

TSP(2018-01-01 00:50:00) | VALUE_ID4 | VAL_ID4 | VALUE_ID5 | VAL_ID5
```

I hope anyone can help me out with this one, cuz it kills me...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I used groupBy on the TSP so I have the following pattern now:

```
TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00):[[ID:1,TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00),VALUE_ID1,VAL_ID1], [ID:3,TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00),VALUE_ID3,VAL_ID3], [ID:5,TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00),VALUE_ID5,VAL_ID5]]

TSP(2018-01-01 00:12:00):[[ID:4,TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00),VALUE_ID4,VAL_ID4]]
```

etc. that's where I got stuck now –

Comment: i guess you have to put all values with the same time in one line. and id=5 has the different date then id=1 by mistake... if yes, just sort the resultset by TSP field. and while it's the same put all you need in one line, if TSP has different value print out new line and new TSP value...

Comment: yea, it was a mistake.
I used groupBy already (edited the topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below Java API for CVS generation:

- [OpenCSV](http://www.baeldung.com/opencsv)
- [Apache Commons CSV](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv)

Both API has read/write API for working with CSV
Examples of APIs:

- [OpenCSV](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/)
- [Apache Commons CSV](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-apache-commons-csv/)

I would prefer to use OpenCSV

Comment: I tried with Apache Commons CSV but can't get the pattern implemented

Comment: Another API you can use is supercsv

Answer (score 1):

I believe [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial) can help you greatly here. Check [this section](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_writing.html#writing-value-by-value) of its tutorial. You can write your rows like this:

```
File outputFile = new File("/path/to/your.csv");
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(outputFile, new CsvWriterSettings());

String currentTime = null;
for(String[] row : getDataFromYourDatabase()){
    if(row[1].equals(currentTime)){ //check the time signature
        writer.addValue(row[0]); // write the ID on a column
        writer.addValue(row[2]); // write the value associated with the ID on the next column
    } else {
        if(currentTime != null){
             writer.writeValuesToRow(); // generates a row.
        }
        currentTime = row[1];
        writer.addValue(row[1]); //writes the time to the first column of the next row
    }
}
```

Assuming method `getDataFromYourDatabase()` returns all rows ordered by the time (i.e. the values that look like this: `TSP(2018-01-01 00:10:00)`) this should work great.

Hope it helps.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can come up with using Fuzzy-Csv (https://github.com/kayr/fuzzy-csv/)

```
package fuzzycsv

import static fuzzycsv.FuzzyStaticApi.reduce

def data = [[ID: 1, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 856830, VAL1: '36,704'],
            [ID: 4, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:12:00', VALUE: 736830, VAL1: '1,14'],
            [ID: 5, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 656830, VAL1: '12,504'],
            [ID: 5, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:50:00', VALUE: 936830, VAL1: '5,18'],
            [ID: 3, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:10:00', VALUE: 736860, VAL1: '3,4'],
            [ID: 4, TSP: '2018-01-01 00:50:00', VALUE: 726830, VAL1: '9,14']]

def list =
        FuzzyCSVTable
                .fromMapList(data)
                .transform('ID') { "VAL_ID${it.ID}" }
                .transform('TSP') { "TSP_(${it.TSP})" }
                .summarize('TSP', reduce { it['ID'] }.az('IDS'))
                .with { tbl(csv.collect { it.flatten() }[1..-1]) }


println(list.toCsvString())
```

output

```
"TSP_(2018-01-01 00:10:00)","VAL_ID1","VAL_ID5","VAL_ID3"
"TSP_(2018-01-01 00:12:00)","VAL_ID4"
"TSP_(2018-01-01 00:50:00)","VAL_ID5","VAL_ID4"
```